# Update CAE linux to latest Ubuntu OS that has been installed along with windows 7

Tags: linux, multi-boot

I am running a dual boot system with CAE Linux and Windows 7 on different drives. Will updating the linux OS affect my windows OS ?? When I boot my computer, Linux OS shows up as the first option followed by Windows.

Thank You.